# How to add object to nested Array using Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I add object to my nested Array in `PartnerSchema`?

I separate documents, because in the future there will be more of nested arrays.

This is my schema:

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

var partnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }]
});

module.exports = {
    Partner: mongoose.model('Partner', partnerSchema),
    Product: mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
}
```

And this is my backend:

```
var campSchema = require('../model/camp-schema');

router.post('/addPartner', function (req, res) {
    new campSchema.Partner({ name : req.body.name }).save(function (err, response) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.json(response);
    });
});

router.post('/addProduct', function (req, res) {
    campSchema.Partner.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.partnerId }, 
        {
        $push: {
            "products": {
                name: req.body.dataProduct.name
            }
        }
    }, { safe: true }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

I can add Partner by using `/addPartner` and it works fine.

Problem is with second function `/addProduct` I can't add Product to Array in Partner Schema. I have an error: `CastError: Cast to undefinded failed for value "[object Object]" at path "products"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the products field in `Partner` model is an array that holds `_id` refs to the `Product` model, you are supposed to push an `_id` to the array, not an object hence Mongoose complains with an error.

You should restructure your code to allow the saving of the `Product` _id ref to the `Partner` model:

```
router.post('/addProduct', function (req, res) {
    var product = new campSchema.Product(req.body.dataProduct);

    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) return throw err;        
        campSchema.Partner.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.body.partnerId,
            { "$push": { "products": product._id } },
            { "new": true },
            function (err, partner) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.json(partner);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: What about name? This code only adding products with id. I have to add also `req.body.dataProduct.name` to name field in products

Comment: There's no need to add the name because Mongoose automatically adds that for you when you do the population. You need to understand the notion of Mongoose population, I suggest you read more [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a4ed4318781680dc3e57f"), "name" : "examplePartner", "products" : [ ObjectId("576a5e54e8b3585818502fc4") ], "__v" : 0 }`

As you can see in products array is only ID. Without name...

Comment: That is what it is supposed to be, just an array with `_id`s. If you understood correctly what Mongoose populate does then you will know it will automatically create the document for you behind the scenes when you are querying the collection. In the instance above, you are saving the data so there is no need to save it as an object because you have defined it in your schema  to use the `ref` property. I encourage you to have a read about the topic [**populate**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) more so that you get a better understanding.

Comment: Ok i understood. Now I wonder if it was a good idea to separate documents. Because how will I display products to specific partner. Before when I had product inside partner, was easy - `li(ng-repeat="product in partner.products")
                                  a(href="#") {{ product.name }}` so maybe I shouldn't separate these documents?

Comment: I would suggest you create a new question since this has the potential of evolving into a [**chameleon question**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/), something that's not encouraged here on SO.

Comment: Other than that your original design seems fine to me, you just have to call the `populate()` method on the `Partner` model to populate the products as well when you do your queries i.e. `Partner.find({}).populate('products').exec(callback)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115309/discussion-between-dipix-and-chridam).